# Bar Charts from multiple columns in Excel using C# .NET

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet with bulk of data( several columns and thousands of rows). However, I would like to express the data in barcharts. I had found a method which gives cell numbers in the code like `A1:B2`, `A3:C3`, etc. But the problem is the excel sheet consists of thousands of rows and several columns. So, I can't give manually. Can anyone suggest a relevant method for this?

Comment: Can you post your current code that makes the Barcharts, but doesn't handle thousands of rows very well?

Comment: Sample code:http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart.htm

Comment: Is the data already in your spreadsheet? Your question implies that it is. This code you've linked to is *writing* the cells to the spreadsheet, *then* plotting it. If you don't need to write it, then just use the code at the end (that plots the chart), and put in your desired cell range from your existing spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you. But the data in Excel changes Week by Week. Is it possible to keep the data in database. I just want to try the following steps: 1. Import data from Excel to Database.2. Export from Database to Excel with bar charts. Will it be helpful for me?